# Can anyone here make me understand this program and what output will I get through this?

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, emu8086

```
DATA SEGMENT
STRING1 DB 11H,22H,33H,44H,55H
MSG1    DB "FOUND$"
MSG2    DB "NOT FOUND$"
SE      DB 34H
DATA ENDS

PRINT MACRO MSG
    MOV AH, 09H
    LEA DX, MSG
    INT 21H
    INT 3
ENDM

CODE SEGMENT
ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA
START:
    MOV AX, DATA
    MOV DS, AX
    MOV AL, SE
    LEA SI, STRING1
    MOV CX, 04H

UP:
    MOV BL,[SI]
    CMP AL, BL
    JZ FO
    INC SI
    DEC CX
    JNZ UP

    PRINT MSG2
    JMP END1
FO:
    PRINT MSG1
END1:
    INT 3

CODE ENDS
END START
```

Comment: Did you try running it in a debugger to see what it does and why?

Comment: yes, I tried running it and I got output too...but I didn't understood this program and actually how to understand the output I got was right or wrong.

Comment: My vote is the equivalent of `memchr`, plus friendly output. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memchr.3.html

Answer (score 3):

The program searches for the byte '34H' within the sequence 11H,22H,33H,44H.

The START section does the following:

- Set DS:SI to the address of STRING1.
- Set AL for the byte to search
  for.
- Set CX for the numbers of bytes to search within STRING1 (4
  bytes).

The loop section does the following:

- Load the byte at DS:SI (from STRING1) into BL
- Compare it with the byte to search for (in AL)
- if bytes are equal (Zero Flag = 1) then print "Found"
- else (not equal) go to the next byte (INC SI), decrement the counter (CX)
- if the counter is zero then exit the loop and print "NOT FOUND"

---

Print Macro:

```
MOV AH, 09H
INT 21H
```

is the MS-DOS call for Print until "$"
`INT 3` means exit program.

It is suspicious that the counter CX is set to 4 but the STRING1 sequence contains 5 bytes. Without really having debugged the program i would say CX = 5 would be correct?

Comment: You are correct that it only searches the first 4 elements of the byte array. CX bein 5 would be correct if the intent was to search the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

My vote is the equivalent of `memchr(s,c,n)`, where `s` is in `SI` (incremented each iteration), `c` is in `BL` (compared with of thing gotten from SI for 'item found' exit condition) and `n` is in `CX` (decremented, to zero if array element equal to `BL` not found, that being other exit condition) plus friendly output (macro containing int21h call). See http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memchr.3.html

Answer (score 0):

It searches for the value `33h` in the byte array `11H,22H,33H,44H,55H`

```
DATA SEGMENT
# Data where we will look up for value
STRING1 DB 11H,22H,33H,44H,55H
# message to be printed out
MSG1 DB "FOUND$"
# yet one message
MSG2 DB "NOT FOUND$"
# program will look up for this value
SE DB 33H

DATA ENDS

# this is PRINT macro- will be used later like a function
PRINT MACRO MSG
# 09H - is a function of interrupt 21h - print to console http://spike.scu.edu.au/~barry/interrupts.html
MOV AH, 09H
LEA DX, MSG
# print message using interrupt 21h
INT 21H
# I think it's exit - check it in the x86 interrupts table if you need
INT 3

ENDM # end of print macro

CODE SEGMENT

ASSUME CS:CODE, DS:DATA

START:

# this is the first line of code
MOV AX, DATA
MOV DS, AX
# copy value of SE (33h) to the AL register so later we can compare it
MOV AL, SE
LEA SI, STRING1

# save in CX length of the data to be looked up for value (actually num or iterations)
MOV CX, 04H

# the main loop starts here
UP:
# copy byte from buffer STRING1 to the BL register
MOV BL,[SI]
# check if AL==BL -> value found
CMP AL, BL

# if AL==BLjump to FO (will print FOUND)
JZ FO
# if not found, 
# move to next byte in STRING1
INC SI
# decrement loop constraint (loop should end before reaching end of string)
DEC CX
# if CX <> 0 loop again
JNZ UP
# if CX==0 print message NOT FOUND
PRINT MSG2
JMP END1
FO:
PRINT MSG1
END1:
INT 3
CODE ENDS

END START
```